# how do i pass a parameter or let sqlplus prompt user to enter an input for an anonymous block?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

below is just a partial snippet of the code.

ultimately, i want to assign user inputs to a global variable which i will use in various parts of the script

```
accept trg_id prompt 'Enter Trg ID > '

declare
v_trg_id VARCHAR2(12) := '&trg_id';
v_test1 VARCHAR2(10000);

begin
    
    select * into v_test1 from db1.test1
    where trg_id = v_trg_id;

end;
```

it seems that the & doesnt work here? // solved

i want **v_trg_id** to be populated with a user input

any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: you can check [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-sqlplus-the/1565925785/ch04s03.html) out

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan tks for the link! to add on, it seems that for anonymous block requires a SELECT .. INTO.. FROM? the normal SELECT.. FROM.. doesnt works?

Comment: @UVERtainment - correct, though some recent versions let query results be passed back to the client. It depends what you want to do with the query results though; and whether you even need PL/SQL. What you showed in the question should sort of work, at least in SQL\*Plus etc. with default define settings; except you may need quotes, so `:= '&trg_id'`. Using `accept` is nicer. But what does "doesn't work" mean? If you get an error then please include it in your question.

Comment: @AlexPoole now im running into an error saying 'not enough values'  in the select into statement. it seems that this is the incorrect way of returning the results into a variable?

Comment: You need one variable for each column in the select list; as you have `select *` that means a variable for every column in your table. Or you can use a record type - see the PL/SQL documentation.